# Псевдокласс :not не дружит с псевдоэлементами?

Tags: css3

Здесь — https://webref.ru/css/not ознакомился с этим ↓

> В качестве селектора могут указываться единичные псевдоклассы, теги, идентификаторы, классы и селекторы атрибутов. Нельзя использовать псевдокласс :not (конструкция :not(:not(...)) запрещена) и **псевдоэлементы**.

По логике вышеизложенного, :not не должен работать с before-after, но, здесь, у меня всё чудненько работает ↓

```
`li:not(:nth-child(1)):after {
        content: '\2386';
        font-size: 24px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        left: 8px;
        display: block;
        color: @sidenav-a;
        font-weight: 600;
    }`
```

Прошу, внести ясность, в суть вопроса.

Comment: "Нельзя использовать" - речь про то, что нельзя использовать ВНУТРИ конструкции `:not`, в случае с псевдоэлементами - нельзя использовать `:not(:before)` (даже не знаю что бы это могло значить, но суть такая)

Comment: Уяснил для себя, спасибки.